# ECS Service restart after deploy new version of docker image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

Hu guys,
I have ec2 cluster with service and instance. Task is based on latest version of docker file which is allocated in ecr. Now I'm looking for simplest way to finish my pipeline with auto "refresh" service when latest image has been deployed. I can't find any feature from aws to resolve this problem, but I found this: https://github.com/fdfk/ecsServiceRestart but unfortunately it doesn't work (can't communicate with my service). But this case inspired me very much because according to author's approach this solution make a duplicate service before update so it provide something like HA without any downtime. Guys is it possible to go throughout these steps without any downtime at all?

1. deploy new version of image,
2. service detect new version of image,
3. auto refresh with implementation new version

Comment: You can reach this by using CodeDeploy and CloudFormation. It depends on how is your pipeline designed.
 This post on AWS blog might interest you:
"the Deploy stage uses CloudFormation to create a new task definition revision that points to the newly built Docker container image and updates the ECS service to use the new task definition revision."

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/continuous-deployment-to-amazon-ecs-using-aws-codepipeline-aws-codebuild-amazon-ecr-and-aws-cloudformation/

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the best way to achieve my goal. So it was very easy - I just have used ecs-deploy https://github.com/fabfuel/ecs-deploy which I have adopted to my pipeline. I set up longer timeout with no warning flag and this script do for me everything what exactly need. In my example I have one cluster with 3 instances and 1 service witch two running tasks (two the same nodes behind load balancer). When I update my docker image in ECR, ecs-deploy runs auto update first instance, and according to blue-green deployment it updates next instances one by one with load balancer links too. So in this way I achieved full automated deployment after accepting merge request (of course I skipped few steps in this describe). I hope that this will be helpful for somebody. Cheers!

Comment: any blog post/steps for your solution please?